# CSS and firefox issue

Tags: css, firefox

The left margin of this `DIV` aligns too far left when on Firefox. It looks fine on Chrome, Safari, and IE. But I can't get it to align with the images below on Firefox. Any help?  Here is the link to the site: http://www.aerlawgroup.com

I have this div tag:

```
<div class="text-box21"> IN THE NEWS</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
.text-box21 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 1.2px;
    padding-bottom: 1.9px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "museo-sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-image:url('http://www.aerlawgroup.com/uploads/2/1/1/5/21159280/6156337_orig.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `width: 282px;` forces the boxes to match the image widths above and below... but then the parent div with the bottom border has a mismatched width of 100% that's set in JS. You would need to update the width there too.

Comment: that didn't work.  I'm using Weebly editor, so maybe that has something to do with it.  I added the width, and you can see the result.

Comment: actually, I changed the indentation to the left.  Now I have a problem that the text in the top right hand box doesn't flush as far to the left in FIREFOX as it does in Safari and Chrome.  Any ideas how to make it so that the CSS positioning goes to same place when viewing on firefox?

Comment: It looks fixed, minus the border.

Comment: yes, the original problem is fixed.  can you please look at it again?  Do you see the text in the box with the gavel.  USING firefox, you see how the text is too far right?  But it's ok on Chrome and Safari?  Any ideas?

Comment: hr.styled-hr { } That's the nuisance element. I'd remove it... or set the same width... or give it a height of zero and set the border on the element in your question, rather than complicate things by relying on another element for the effect.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Where is that element?  You mean in the HTML code?

Comment: Yeah. You can either find it in html and remove it, or you can style it in CSS by its class name `hr.styled-hr { }` - it's currently in 'sites.css' at line 1. Just update it there.

Comment: crap.  I think that something that Weebly adds without me being able to change it.  Any other workaround u suggest?  And thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: One sec. Do you have access to the CSS? The HTML? Add the following in your CSS file: `hr.styled-hr { width: 282px !important; float: left; }`

Comment: I have access to both.  However, Weebly inserts its own code too upon publishing.